# Group orders and get a list of the products of each order

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, group-by

I have a database that contains 3 tables: user, orders, products and order_products this way :
[image: Database picture]

I tried to get orders and their products then group them by orders.id this way :

```
SELECT `orders`.*, `product`.* 
FROM `product`, `orders` 
JOIN `order_products` op ON op.orderid=orders.id 
GROUP BY orders.id
```

but it only gets me the last product from each order.
Is it possible to get each order by itself and a list of products of that order ? I really need your help.

Comment: remove the GROUP BY

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax everywhere. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Answer (score 1):

If you just want one column, such as the product title concatenated into a string (which is a reasonable interpretation of the title of your question), then you can use `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT o.*, GROUP_CONCAT(p.title)
FROM orders o JOIN
     order_products op
     ON op.orderid = o.id JOIN
     product p
     ON op.productid = p.productid
GROUP BY o.id;
```